# Java redirect from servlet removes querystring

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a maven web app that does form authentication, but on successful login it removes my URL parameter `debug`

`http://localhost:8080/TestProject/?debug`

Changes to --> `http://localhost:8080/TestProject/`

I use that parm for in the index.html page for some logic

Not sure what I did to make this happen

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">  
<display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name> 


<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>test/index.html</welcome-file> 
 </welcome-file-list>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>AuthFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.test.AuthClass</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>AuthClass</filter-name>  
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
<dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

let me know if you need to see more

Comment: Where is the redirect done? If it has been done from your AuthClass then you will have to add that request parameter again. This is expected behavior. As soon as you redirect or forward, all the request parameters will be lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you used url rewriting in your filter code .
Filter's dofilter method has request and response objects .Check your dofilter method

Comment: Thanks for your response   It is coming back as `httpResponse.sendRedirect(requestedURL);`

Comment: String requestedURL = request.getParameter("requestURL");

Comment: I tried something like this but it's coming back as null --`String requestQueryString = (httpRequest.getQueryString() != null ? "?" + httpRequest.getQueryString() : "");     The doFilter method has `ServletRequest request` btw
  `

Comment: You can use jd-gui tool to decode your class files to java files.most of the code will be displayed  except for you might not get the comments you put on your actual java files before building the war file for deployment.

Comment: Not sure how that helps?